# I want to bind a textbox value to another textbox while typing, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code. But I am not getting an output.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#txtOpenQty').keyup(function (e) {
         var txtVal = $(this).val();
         $('#txtCloseQuantity').val(txtVal);
     });

     $('#txtCloseQuantity').keyup(function (e) {
         var txtVal = $(this).val();
         $('#txtOpenQty').val(txtVal);
     });
});
```

Comment: are you getting any console error on browser as this looks fine to me

Comment: no i am not getting any error but the value is not getting binded..

Comment: please share jsfiddle if you can, so that we can help you better

Comment: what browser you are using ?

Comment: i am using a master page...

Comment: is there something to do with it in the code?

Comment: no i mean which web browser you are using IE, Mozilla or chrome?? and your code is correct there is no issue

Comment: hi i have tested your code. its working! check here http://jsfiddle.net/6Bpua/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
<input type="text" id="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" />


$('#one').keyup(function(e) {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    $('#two').attr("value", txtVal);
});
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/873ym/) for example.

update:

```
<input type="text" id="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" />


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script>

$('#one').keyup(function(e) {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    $('#two').val(txtVal);
});
</script>
```

Comment: few questions for you, which browser are you using? have you include jQuery properly?

Comment: sorry for trouble .i am a fresher in programming so i am confused.Using chrome.

Comment: you must be getting some error check console in your browser.

Comment: I have a smilar issue that, its binding from the second value, first value says empty whatever i type

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<textarea id="o"></textarea>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>



<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               console.log('jquery in');
               $('#o').keyup(function(e){
                  console.log($(this).val()); 
                  $('#t').val($(this).val());
               });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input width="5" size="5/" col="5" value="23232" id="txtOpenQty">
<input width="5" size="5/" col="5" value="2323" id="txtCloseQuantity">
```

And in JS O copied your code as it is.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
       $('#txtOpenQty').keyup(function (e) {
              var txtVal = $(this).val();
              $('#txtCloseQuantity').val(txtVal);
       });
       $('#txtCloseQuantity').keyup(function (e) {
           var txtVal = $(this).val();
           $('#txtOpenQty').val(txtVal);
       });
   });

   </script>
```

I tried the same example its working fine for me, can you please explain in more details,
where are you writing this code, or what is HTML you are using?

Comment: i am writing it inside html